# Cardinality of Infinite Sets using injections

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ and $B$ be two infinite sets. If I can show an injective function from $A$ to $B$ and another injective function from $B$ to $A$, can I then say that they have the same cardinality?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. This is known as the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) (apparently also sometimes Schröder-Bernstein theorem).

Comment: It's worth noting that this **does not** require the axiom of choice - it's very explicit (although not *constructive* in the strict logical sense). Incidentally, I've heard it in lecture called "Cantor-Schroeder," "Schroeder-Bernstein," and "Cantor-Bernstein" but never all three; in a talk I gave I called it the ${CBS\choose 2}$-theorem.